# div buttons not working in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm having trouble making the div buttons on [this simple slideshow](http://povesteata.kappa.ro/fb) to work. I've used jQuery and I've tried to stay away from things that don't work in IE (e.g. split).

The IE debugger shows that the div with the id "next" is properly placed, and i've found no errors in my javascript. Still, the div doesn't have the click event binded and the css style of **cursor: pointer** isn't applied.

How should I solve this problem?
Many thanks.

Comment: Looks like CSS issue, not JS... the parent DIV is "above" the nested DIV's so the click never reach to the proper place. Try setting proper `z-index` and it should work fine.

Comment: Also you should check your html (e.g. [http://validator.w3.org/](http://validator.w3.org/)); not only your first line failed.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard you've set me on the right path with that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shadow Wizard's comment was spot on. After realizing that this is a z-index bug, i've checked the [squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug link](http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/) for clues but that didn't work for me so, since i was under time pressure, i've decided to replace the `<img>`tag with a div and set background on it.